# Selenium Chromedriver executable needs to be in path ( IT IS)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Installed Selenium and the latest stable Chromedriver built.

As suggested I put it into the environment variable path:

[image]

My code looks like this :

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver', options=options)

timeout = 3
```

The error that I am getting is :

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I even tried the following in the command line :

```
chromedriver --whitelisted-ips=""
```

Can someone please provide some help how I can resolve  this.

The whole output error is this :

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
     77         except TypeError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in **init**(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    774                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 775                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    776         except:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1177                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1178                                          startupinfo)
   1179             finally:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3b7827e2d128> in <module>
      2 from selenium import webdriver
      3 
----> 4 driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
      5 driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
      6 time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     71             service_args=service_args,
     72             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 73         self.service.start()
     74 
     75         try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
---> 83                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     84                 )
     85             elif err.errno == errno.EACCES:
```

Comment: Just put chromedriver in c:\windows - there's no point adding junk to your path.

Comment: I hope this is a joke. Adding junk to your windows directory is far worse than adding junk to your path. (it would be an option to change PATH locally though before calling the script.)

Answer (score 0):

The path entry needs to be `C:\Users\skpok\Downloads\chromedriver_win32` and not `C:\Users\skpok\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe`.

The `PATH` environment variable lists **folders** in which to search for programs. It doesn't list the programs themselves.

*(With your current configuration, the full path of the file would have to be `C:\Users\skpok\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe\chromedriver.exe` to be found.)*

---

Also, it seems you are actually *specifying* the chrome driver path here:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver', options=options)
```

The path `./driver/chromedriver` conflicts with the path you showed before... Try removing this argument so that it *actually* looks in the `PATH`, or specify the correct file path here!

Comment: I tried both suggestions, and nothing changes :( Where could I have gone wrong or how can I find the mistake ?

Comment: If you only recently added this entry, log off and on again or restart your computer.

Comment: Tried that as well .. just does not want to work :(

Comment: I noticed another issue now and I updated my answer. You are specifying a file path actually: `./driver/chromedriver`!

Comment: Good Catch, unfortunately it still doesnt work. This is so frustrating :(

Comment: Use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and set a filter "path" "contains" "chromedriver", to see what paths it _tries_ to use (and fails) so it can become clearer how expectation and reality differ.